# I derived a formula for $[x!]^\prime$. Is it correct?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

The starting point was that $ \Gamma'(x+1)=\Gamma(x+1)\psi(x+1)$ where $\psi(x+1)=-\gamma+H_{x}$ . Hence $$ [x!]' = x!\biggl[-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^{x}\frac{1}{k}\biggl]$$ For example $ [4!]' = 24[-\gamma+1+1/2+1/3+1/4]$ which gives $36.1462$ that, put in the tangent equation, gives us exactly the tangent for $x=4$! Let me know if I made any mistakes in the derivation/generalization!

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Ok, thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that
$$
\partial_x\Gamma(x)\bigg|_{x=5}=\Gamma(x)\psi(x)\bigg|_{x=5}=4!\left(\frac{25}{12}-\gamma\right).
$$
The problem with saying that this is the derivative of the factorial function is that to calculate a derivative you must extend the factorial $x!:\Bbb N_0\to\Bbb N_0$ to a continuos function.  The gamma function is one way to do this.  But now consider another continuous interpolation of the factorial, namely, the [Hadamard gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_gamma_function):
$$
H(x)=\frac{\psi ^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma (1-x)}.
$$
Just like the gamma function we have for $n\in\Bbb N_0$ that $H(n)=(n-1)$!. Calculating the derivative and evaluating at $x=5$ gives
$$
\partial_xH(x)\bigg|_{x=5}=4!\left(\frac{3}{2}-\gamma +\log 2\right),
$$
which differs from the result we got using the gamma function.  For this reason, it does not make sense to call one result or the other a derivative of the factorial.